# Problem with cmd install electron-packager

Tags: javascript, electron

I installed electron and nodejs and finished my project when i install electron packager from cmd  it succeed without problem but when i call it execute there is no such command or directory called electron-packager

I wrote in cmd : npm install electron-packager 
Success
But when i wrote electron-packager . 
Error is electron-packager isnt a command or a directory

Comment: `npx electron-packager` or put `"scripts": { "build": "electron-packager" }` in your `package.json` and run `npm run build`.

Answer (score 0):

you should run electron-packager .  ( dont forget the dot at the end , a dot after a blank space )